# Slick Slider удаляет id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider-slick.js

Использую на странице slick slider. Использую его для аудиозаписей. Слайдер бесконечный. Когда дохожу до последней аудиозаписи и пытыюсь снова включить первую, она не проигрывается и у неё пропадает id, причина того, что не проигрывается в этом. Как можно исправить это? Не могу найти в интернете ничего похожего. Спасибо!

```
  $('.slider-audio').slick({
    
                infinite: true,
                dots: false,
                arrows: true,
    
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 1024,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                            infinite: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 767,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 575,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                            slidesToScroll: 1
                        }
                    }
                    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
                    // settings: "unslick"
                    // instead of a settings object
                ]
            });
```

HTML

```
<div id="play-station" class="Episodes slider-audio">
                    <div>
                       <div class="episode">                     
                            <div class="section-winners-bars bars">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="play section-winners-play section-winners-playactive">
                                <audio src="{$this->getPlugin()->getImgFile('audio/Final1.mp3')}" id="audio1" class="audio"></audio>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div class="episode">
                    <div class="section-winners-bars bars">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="play section-winners-play section-winners-playactive">
                                 <audio src="{$this->getPlugin()->getImgFile('audio/Final2_1.mp3')}" id="audio2" class="audio"></audio>
                            </div>
    
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div class="episode">
                     <div class="section-winners-bars bars">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="play section-winners-play section-winners-playactive ">
                                 <audio src="{$this->getPlugin()->getImgFile('audio/Final3.mp3')}" id="audio3" class="audio"></audio>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div class="episode">
                         <div class="section-winners-bars bars">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="play section-winners-play section-winners-playactive ">
                                 <audio src="{$this->getPlugin()->getImgFile('audio/Final4.mp3')}" id="audio4" class="audio"></audio>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
```

Comment: подождите, надо заварить кофе и погадать на гуще. или можете код свой привести, что дам больше шансов на удачный исход

Comment: Извините, уже добавила

Comment: Предполагаю, что айдишник удаляется потому что слик для зацикливания делает клонов, а 2 айдишника на странице НИЗЯ. может айди перевести в data-id и пробовать с него запускать?

Comment: К сожалению это не подходит, так как id используется для кода для проигрывания

Comment: А есть сложность изменить код так чтобы за это отвечал не id а дата атрибут?